# Not able to subscribe to destination using wscat on windows command

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket

I am getting started for building websocket app. I am using a spring boot app for websocket backend and need help on which is the right command to use for subscribing to a particular destination using wscat, I am using @SendToUser,Currently its able to register the user  in the CustomHandshakeHandler

```
public class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
        @Override
        protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                          WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                          Map<String, Object> attributes) {
            
                LOGGER.info(request.getBody().toString());
            
}}
```

with the command

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8080/ws
```

however i need to invoke the handler below which I am not sure is the right way to invoke using wscat

```
@MessageMapping("/ws")
    @SendToUser("/ws")
    public String recieveStartRequest(@Payload String message, Principal principal) {
        LOGGER.info("Received greeting message {} from {}", message, principal.getName());
        return "Hello world !";
    }
```

in the debug i can find that

```
clientInboundChannel added UserDestinationMessageHandler[DefaultUserDestinationResolver[prefix=/user/]]
brokerChannel added UserDestinationMessageHandler[DefaultUserDestinationResolver[prefix=/user/]]
```

but when I need the above message handler be invoked so I can use the **@Payload String message** for specific data

Comment: Hi! Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: no Sir, not yet , have you faced similar issues?

Comment: Hey hi) Yes, sir. I resolved similar issue 2 weeks ago. Check your configuration class and check your endpoints if you use Spring Security.